# How to revert form value to model value in a component that's using one-way data binding?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm building a service in angular 2 that allows a user to edit multiple forms on a page, and then save all the changes at once. I'm running into a problem trying to add the functionality for resetting the forms if a user decides not to save their changes.

I'm using one-way data binding on my forms combined with an EventEmitter to manually handle changes to the input fields.

```
<input class="form-control" [ngModel]="model" (ngModelChange)="change($event)"/>
```

Basically, when the user makes changes to any of the forms, I manually capture the change with `ngModelChange` and cache it in my service. This allows for the model to remain unchanged until the user saves and an HTTP response returns with the updated model. Therefore, I'm able to preserve the old values in case the user wants to reset everything, while also successfully tracking changes in a service. ***My problem is that due to the nature of one way data binding, I can't get the forms to rerender because the model never changed in the first place***. So, is there a way to manually trigger a rerender of the form inputs to revert them to the model's value?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the form's values back to the unchanged model via the `FormGroup` [reset](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#reset-anchor) api. I'm assuming your input is part of a larger form, using `ngForm`.

Most of the examples I've seen use reset to clear the form i.e. clearing the value and the `touched` & `dirty` flags.

But `reset` also allows you to provide a map of the control values you want, which you would get from the values in your model.

I suspect I'm going to want this behaviour on the some forms in my project soon, so I'll be interested to hear how this goes for you.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with above answer. You can have this kind of code to take a 'snapshot' of your FormGroup before editing:

```
...
private snapshot: any;
private formGroup: FormGroup;

private takeSnapshot() {
    this.snapshot = {};
    for (let id in this.formGroup.controls) {
      this.snapshot[id] = this.formGroup.controls[id].value;
    }
}
...
// before editing, call this.takeSnapshot()
```

... then, when you want to revert, you pass the snapshot to the reset() method of the formgroup:

```
this.formGroup.reset(this.snapshot)
```